# Different behavior of \gcd analogs within babel russian and serbianc?

Tags: babel, hooks

Consider the following two analog MWEs:

1.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

%\let\gcd\NOD

\listfiles

\begin{document}

$\gcd{(a, b)}$, $\NOD{(a, b)}$

\end{document}
```

2. 

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[serbianc]{babel}

%\let\gcd\NZD

\listfiles

\begin{document}

$\gcd{(a, b)}$, $\NZD{(a, b)}$

\end{document}
```

Respective outputs, both are expected and correct:

1. [image]
2. [image]

On the other hand, after uncommenting `%\let\gcd...` lines, I get:

1. [image]
2. error

   c:/Users/usr/Downloads/test/sr.tex:13: Undefined control sequence.
    \gcd

   l.13 $\gcd
   {(a, b)}$, $\NZD{(a, b)}$
   The control sequence at the end of the top line
   of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
   misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type` I' and the correct
   spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
   and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

I would say that 1. has expected behavior, and that `serbianc` does not activate extras (at least the `\NZD`) before the `\AtBeginDocument` hook or so.

Should these two MWEs behave the same way?

I cannot paste both whole logs due to 30000 characters limit, here are just `listfiles` outputs:

1.

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2021/02/12 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2021/02/12 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 fontenc.sty
  t2aenc.def    2005/09/27 v1.0i Cyrillic encoding definition file
  t2aenc.dfu    2021/01/27 v1.2l UTF-8 support for inputenc
  t2acmr.fd    2001/08/11 v1.0a Computer Modern Cyrillic font definitions
inputenc.sty    2021/02/14 v1.3d Input encoding file
   babel.sty    2021/07/22 3.63 The Babel package
 bblopts.cfg    2005/09/08 v0.1 add Arabic and Farsi to "declared" options of babel
russianb.ldf    2021/01/10 1.3m Russian support for the Babel system
l3backend-pdftex.def    2021-08-04 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
 ***********
```

2. 

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2021/02/12 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2021/02/12 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 fontenc.sty
  t2aenc.def    2005/09/27 v1.0i Cyrillic encoding definition file
  t2aenc.dfu    2021/01/27 v1.2l UTF-8 support for inputenc
  t2acmr.fd    2001/08/11 v1.0a Computer Modern Cyrillic font definitions
inputenc.sty    2021/02/14 v1.3d Input encoding file
   babel.sty    2021/07/22 3.63 The Babel package
 bblopts.cfg    2005/09/08 v0.1 add Arabic and Farsi to "declared" options of babel
serbianc.ldf    2021/04/10 3.1 Serbian Cyrillic support for the Babel system
l3backend-pdftex.def    2021-08-04 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
 ***********
```

Comment: I guess the command `\NZD` gets defined only at `\begin{document}`, and is undefined before. Therefore, you set `\gcd` to an undefined command. Move the `\let` statement to after `\begin{document}`, then it will probably work.

Comment: I know how to avoid the error. The thread is about "which `babel` module is implemented the right way, and how to fix the other".

Comment: There is no right or wrong here I think, different babel languages implement different sets of commands.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle "right or wrong" - not so strictly, of course. It is more about convenience, that analog things are implemented the analog way (and maybe the way that `babel` author thought extras should be implemented).

Answer (score 2):

Use `\addto\extras<language>`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian,serbianc]{babel}

\addto\extrasrussian{\let\gcd\NOD}
\addto\extrasserbianc{\let\gcd\NZD}

\begin{document}

This is \languagename

$\gcd(a, b)$, $\NZD(a, b)$

\selectlanguage{russian}

This is \languagename

$\gcd(a, b)$, $\NOD(a, b)$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**\usepackage[russian]{babel}:** Under Unix/GNU-Linux with TeXlive 2021, the command

```
find /usr/local/texlive/2021 -name 'russian*' -exec fgrep -q NOD '{}' \; -print
```

yields the line

```
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-russian/russianb.ldf
```

In this file, we find the following code:

```
\if@uni@ode
  \def\nod{\mathop{\mathrm{н.о.д.}}\nolimits}
  \def\nok{\mathop{\mathrm{н.о.к.}}\nolimits}
  \def\NOD{\mathop{\mathrm{НОД}}\nolimits}
  \def\NOK{\mathop{\mathrm{НОК}}\nolimits}
  \def\Proj{\mathop{\mathrm{Пр}}\nolimits}
\else
  \def\nod{\mathop{\textnormal{\cyrn.\cyro.\cyrd.}}\nolimits}
  \def\nok{\mathop{\textnormal{\cyrn.\cyro.\cyrk.}}\nolimits}
  \def\NOD{\mathop{\textnormal{\CYRN\CYRO\CYRD}}\nolimits}
  \def\NOK{\mathop{\textnormal{\CYRN\CYRO\CYRK}}\nolimits}
  \def\Proj{\mathop{\textnormal{\CYRP\cyrr}}\nolimits}
\fi
```

This means that the commands are immediately defined when the style file is loaded.

**\usepackage[serbianc]{babel}:** Under Unix/GNU-Linux with TeXlive 2021, the command

```
find /usr/local/texlive/2021 -name 'serbianc*' -exec fgrep -q NZD '{}' \; -print
```

yields the line

```
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-serbianc/serbianc.ldf
```

In this file, we find the following code:

```
\addto\extrasserbianc{%
  \babel@save\nzs \babel@save\nzd
  \babel@save\NZS \babel@save\NZD
  \if@srbc@uni@ode
    \def\nzs{\mathop{\mathrm{нзс}}\nolimits}
    \def\nzd{\mathop{\mathrm{нзд}}\nolimits}
    \def\NZS{\mathop{\mathrm{НЗС}}\nolimits}
    \def\NZD{\mathop{\mathrm{НЗД}}\nolimits}
  \else
    \def\nzs{\mathop{\textnormal{\cyrn\cyrz\cyrs}}\nolimits}
    \def\nzd{\mathop{\textnormal{\cyrn\cyrz\cyrd}}\nolimits}
    \def\NZS{\mathop{\textnormal{\CYRN\CYRZ\CYRS}}\nolimits}
    \def\NZD{\mathop{\textnormal{\CYRN\CYRZ\CYRD}}\nolimits}
  \fi}
```

The token list `\extrasserbianc` becomes part of the at-begin-document-hook.

**Which one is better?** Sometimes packages want/have to make sure that their definitions are executed last (after other packages), or that at the time of the execution, other setups have been completed. In this case it is better to postpone the definitions until `\begin{document}`. Otherwise it is more straightforward and maybe safer to define the commands immediately (safer e.g. when you want to make sure that the redefinition of your command throws an error). Check the files in

```
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-*
```

to find out how this is handled in different languages.